# For anidado para comparar los registros de un dataframe

Tags: python

Quiero hacer un for anidado en python, donde comparar todos los registros de un dataframe registro a registro, esto he intentado hasta ahora (la condición compara si el registro del primer for tiene fecha Nulo y el registro del segundo for también):

```
for i in df.index:
    for j in df.index:
        if i!=j and df['idDCL'][i]==df['idDCL'][j] and pd.isnull(df['fechaFin'][i])==True and pd.isnull(df['fechaFin'][j])==True:
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? En todo caso, **hay que intentar evitar bucles** cuando se trabaja con dataframes pandas, ya que pandas incluye sus propios métodos _vectorizados_ que iteran muchísimo más rápido. ¿Puedes explicar más claramente qué comparación es la que intentas hacer, y con qué objetivo, quizás con un ejemplo que muestre un pequeño df con datos de muestra?

Comment: hola! sí, sé que los for anidados no son la solución, pero no sé que función de pandas utilizar. La idea es comparar los registros con mismo identificador (idDCL) y comprobar si la fechaFin del registro del primer for es null y la fechaFin del registro del segundo for es null. Paso enlace para descargar el dataframe: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ipS5FQp7wIt6FSremMCFcgINHU_qdG0t?usp=sharing

Comment: Pero comprobar esa condición para qué? Qué quieres hacer en los casos en que la codición se cumpla? Ah, y el enlace a drive no es público (requiere solicitar acceso)

Comment: el dataframe hace referencia a viajes, y hemos encontrado un problema en él. Si dos viajes sin fecha fin y con el mismo identificador están en el dataframe, los metemos en otro dataframe y lanzamos un reporte en csv para tenerlos localizados. El enlace te lo vuelvo a pasar: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ljj2Nr_xr_1RX9sL1pnsxR_ZCHDWovqwztMLInVPZO8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Los datos

Se tiene un dataframe entre cuyas columnas hay dos que son de interés, llamadas "idDCL" y "fechaFin". Un trozo de este dataframe sería:

```html
     idCDU   idDCL  ...      fechaActivacion             fechaFin
0  AAA-018  557DGQ  ...  2021-02-18 16:36:40  2021-02-28 21:04:51
1  AAB-200  097BAS  ...  2021-04-22 13:30:07  2021-08-17 22:35:59
2  AAC-013  090CND  ...  2021-09-12 11:51:37  2021-09-20 12:22:59
3  AAC-371  622QQD  ...                  NaN   2021-06-14 9:46:50
4  AAD-466  638HUB  ...  2021-06-21 18:54:51                  NaN
```

En la columna `"idDCL"` puede aparecer el mismo valor repetido muchas veces. Por ejemplo, el valor "557DGQ" aparece diez veces:

```html
>>> print(df[df.idDCL=="557DGQ"])

         idCDU   idDCL  ...      fechaActivacion             fechaFin
0      AAA-018  557DGQ  ...  2021-02-18 16:36:40  2021-02-28 21:04:51
4387   EGC-712  557DGQ  ...  2021-03-09 19:38:08  2021-04-26 13:00:53
5504   FJH-821  557DGQ  ...   2021-05-11 9:18:08   2021-05-11 9:32:50
6800   GRG-384  557DGQ  ...  2021-05-19 15:34:21   2021-05-24 8:54:50
8019   HXM-326  557DGQ  ...  2021-03-04 16:32:08  2021-03-04 21:08:59
8023   HXQ-144  557DGQ  ...   2021-05-11 9:17:09   2021-05-11 9:18:07
12238  MDG-186  557DGQ  ...   2021-05-03 9:06:23   2021-05-03 9:54:15
14931  OTS-052  557DGQ  ...   2021-05-19 7:53:51   2021-05-19 9:55:28
16662  QMM-242  557DGQ  ...   2021-05-11 9:33:01  2021-05-17 11:52:29
23961  XRW-652  557DGQ  ...   2021-04-29 9:32:31   2021-05-03 9:06:22
```

En algunos casos en `fechaFin` aparece `NaN`. Algunos de los idDCL pueden tener un NaN o más de uno, por ejemplo, le pasa a "534OUT" que aparece 13 veces pero en dos de ellas tiene NaN en fechaFin.

```html
>>> print(df[df.idDCL=="534OUT"])

         idCDU   idDCL  ...      fechaActivacion             fechaFin
142    ADO-478  534OUT  ...  2020-10-14 15:58:04  2020-11-01 16:44:32
4225   EBR-429  534OUT  ...   2021-05-12 9:08:10  2021-05-12 10:31:34
6068   FXT-010  534OUT  ...   2021-05-19 7:08:17   2021-05-19 7:12:23
8734   IPS-343  534OUT  ...   2021-05-14 8:04:34   2021-05-14 8:07:24
9277   JCU-926  534OUT  ...  2021-01-05 21:26:19  2021-01-06 15:04:56
11704  LOT-549  534OUT  ...   2021-05-14 8:50:55   2021-05-14 9:32:16
14642  OMH-138  534OUT  ...  2021-01-11 14:18:00  2021-03-10 15:45:40
15799  PPO-756  534OUT  ...   2021-05-12 9:03:09   2021-05-12 9:06:28
19128  SXS-454  534OUT  ...   2021-05-19 7:47:41                  NaN
19533  THQ-267  534OUT  ...  2021-05-12 10:32:35  2021-05-13 12:55:42
21814  VOF-283  534OUT  ...                  NaN                  NaN
22148  VWN-535  534OUT  ...  2020-07-23 10:48:24  2020-07-23 11:00:07
26263  ZZT-611  534OUT  ...  2021-05-11 15:17:20  2021-05-11 15:58:42
```

### El problema planteado

(Tal como yo lo entendí, corrígeme en comentarios si me he equivocado)

Encontrar todos aquellos valores de `idDCL` para los cuales en la columna `fechaFin` haya dos o más NaN.

### La solución

Agrupar por `idDCL` y para cada grupo contar cuántos `NaN` hay, quedándonos solo con (filtrando) los grupos que tengan más de 1 NaN. Del resultado nos quedamos con la columna idDCL, que convertimos en conjunto para eliminar duplicados:

```py
ids = set(df.groupby("idDCL").filter(lambda x: x.fechaFin.isna().sum()>1).idDCL)
```

Esto nos da el conjunto de `ids` (idDCL) que tienen dos o más NaN en fechaFin. Podemos echar un vistazo al resultado:

```py
>>> print(ids)
{'206NIO', '999EBF', '517QMS', '130VTQ', '406LWW', '529KFZ', '389LCG', 
'753NND', '738WSS', '709RAP', '102BKR', '421LMV', '648RIP', '931FUO', 
'823TCA', '057EFS', '759CRI', '401KRY', '042LAD', '502SFJ', '427UBT', 
'322UTU', '047IYT', '053PHC', '819FTL', '431FMH', '784ITU', '093GFK', 
'815PXN', '224VUQ', '251NLF', '874SPB', '053CFW', '512LTV', '716XGW', 
'516FDE', '702RGE', '401WHA', '025ITJ', 'DCL_034', '583AEK', 'ERROR', 
'478LZR', '132ZJL', '534OUT', '572QXO', '434TPX', '966QUX', '517DBK', 
'001ITJ', '381HXF', '034EPI', '729DSI', '247UUV', '593YMN', '181RFD', 
'619EMC', '441IDT'}
```

Son 58 casos.

Si ahora queremos ver las filas completas en las que ocurre el problema, podemos usar estos `ids` para filtrar el dataframe completo (junto con la condición de que la `fechaFin` sea `NaN`):

```
problemas = df[df.idDCL.isin(ids) & df.fechaFin.isna()]
```

Este es el dataframe que buscabas. Puedes volcarlo a csv o hacer lo que quieras con él. Por ejemplo, veamos cómo comienza (ordenando por la columna idDCL para que salgan juntos los del mismo idDCL):

```
>>> print(problemas.sort_values(by="idDCL").head(10))

         idCDU   idDCL  ...      fechaActivacion fechaFin
8014   HXI-850  001ITJ  ...  2021-10-15 20:36:27      NaN
20752  UNI-390  001ITJ  ...  2021-05-12 13:57:15      NaN
11292  LEC-358  025ITJ  ...                  NaN      NaN
9606   JLO-450  025ITJ  ...  2021-09-09 19:24:27      NaN
16210  QAJ-307  034EPI  ...  2021-11-12 14:31:23      NaN
18341  SCW-028  034EPI  ...  2021-05-13 10:35:23      NaN
24676  YKX-045  042LAD  ...  2021-06-30 15:57:36      NaN
7860   HTI-370  042LAD  ...  2021-09-01 15:24:48      NaN
22426  WEA-371  047IYT  ...   2021-05-19 7:47:40      NaN
11988  LWK-060  047IYT  ...                  NaN      NaN
```

Como ves, se ha evitado hacer un bucle for. No digamos ya dos bucles for anidados, lo que tendría una complejidad O(n^2) que en un dataframe tan grande como este supondría varios segundos de procesamiento (mi solución termina en menos de 1s)

Comment: Hola! Es justo lo que estaba buscando, exactamente el dataframe de abajo, ya que necesito los registros. Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda!